# How to change unwanted behavior in a method

Tags: c++

We have some classes:

```
struct HttpRequest {
    std::string url;
};

struct HttpResponse {
    int          status_code;
    std::string  status_text;
    std::string  content;
};

struct HttpClient {
    void execute(HttpRequest const& req, HttpResponse& resp);
};

size_t
appender(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    auto& ct = * reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(userp);
    size_t bytes = size * nmemb;

    ct.append(reinterpret_cast<char*>(contents), bytes);
    return bytes;
}

void HttpClient::execute(HttpRequest const& req, HttpResponse& resp)
{
    auto curl = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, req.url.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, appender);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &resp.content);
    // header callback etc.

    CURLcode code = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    if (code != CURLE_OK) {
        throw std::runtime_error("curl fail");
    }

    return; // enjoy your HttpResponse
}
```

We used them like this:

```
bool fatal(std::runtime_error const& rte) {
    return rte.what()[0] == 'F'; // if it starts with F, it's fatal
    // not the actual implementation :)
}

const int retries = 7;

int do_something(std::string const& url)
{
    HttpClient client;
    HttpRequest req{ url };

    for (int r = 0; r < retries; ++r) try {
        HttpResponse resp;

        client.execute(req, resp);
        //
        if (resp.status_code / 100 == 2) { // a 2xx success code
            return std::stoi(resp.content);
        }
        else { // maybe a 4xx client error or 5xx server error
            throw std::runtime_error("HTTP error");
        }
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error const& e) {
        if (fatal(e))
            throw;
        else
            continue; // retry
    }

    // ran out of retries
    throw std::runtime_error("out of retries");
}
```

and all was good.
However, somebody implemented a different pattern:

```
int worker(HttpRequest const& req, HttpResponse& resp)
{
    HttpClient client;
    for (int r = 0; r < retries; ++r) try {
        client.execute(req, resp);
        //
        if (resp.status_code / 100 == 2) { // a 2xx success code
            return std::stoi(resp.content);
        }
        else { // maybe a 4xx client error or 5xx server error
            throw std::runtime_error("HTTP error");
        }
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error const& e) {
        if (fatal(e))
            throw;
        else
            continue; // retry
    }

    // ran out of retries
    throw std::runtime_error("out of retries");
}

int do_something_else(std::string const& url)
{
    HttpRequest req{ url };
    HttpResponse resp;
    return worker(req, resp);
}
```

and now we discovered that we have unwanted behavior in `HttpClient::execute` : if the HttpResponse is not empty on entry (for example, we got a 503 Service unavailable, retry, and get a 200 OK), `execute` just appends to the existing content. This is not what we want: we already acted on the 503 response and we don't want the content of the 200 reply appended to whatever content the 503 reply had.

We went through our code and found several usages similar to `do_something` and only one `do_something_else`. We never ever needed the (accidental) ability to append to an existing response.

---

The question is, how do we fix this and make sure we don't run into surprises again? I can see several options:

- Leave everything as it is; clear the HttpResponse manually inside `do_something_else`; document the behavior (not ideal; people don't always read the documentation :)
- Change `HttpClient::execute` to clear the HttpResponse on entry. I dislike quietly changing the behavior behind the same interface (plus we need to change the unit tests).
- Add a wrapper member to HttpClient that clears the HttpResponse and then calls the original `HttpClient::execute`. This has the advantage that if we ever want the appending behavior, it's available. The disadvantage is that people might get the appending behavior inadvertently.
- Same as above, but rename the existing one to e.g. `execute_append` and call the new one `execute` (again, different behavior behind the same interface).
- Change `execute` to accept just a HttpRequest and return a HttpResponse by value. Because there's always a fresh HttpResponse created inside `execute`, appending is not a problem. Any performance penalty that remains after [NRVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) is dwarfed by millisecond-to-second delays while performing HTTP. The real downside is that we have several unit-tests where `HttpClient::execute` is mocked via googlemock. If we change the signature, we'll have to change all the mocks and also every expectation that was doing SetArgReferee will have to be changed to Returns.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

`HttpClient::execute`'s job appears to be to send an `HTTP` request, and return a response.

If so, then passing an `HttpResponse` object to it as a parameter makes little sense.

`execute()` should simply take a `req` parameter, and return the `HttpResponse`.

A modern C++11 compiler is going to optimize away most of the overhead of returning a non-POD object, thanks to move semantics, leaving you with clean, unambiguous code, with no potential side effects.